# car moving body in box2d with cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, iphone, box2d, cocos2d-x, physics

i have car body and 2 tiers as seprate images .

how to fix as  car body(box2d with cocos2d-x) and moving animation.(i need to rotate tier) and jumping etc.,?

in normal cocos2d-x i can make something like this..

```
car = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("car.png");
car->setPosition(ccp(car->getContentSize().width/2+30, car->getContentSize().height-19));
this->addChild(car, 10);

tire = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("tire.png");
tire->setPosition(ccp(tire->getContentSize().width/2+43, tire->getContentSize().height+8));
this->addChild(tire, 10);

tire1 = CCSprite::spriteWithFile("tire.png");
tire1->setPosition(ccp(tire->getContentSize().width/2+136, tire->getContentSize().height+8));
this->addChild(tire1, 10);

CCRotateBy *Rot = CCRotateBy::actionWithDuration (1.0f, 360);
CCRepeatForever *rep = CCRepeatForever::actionWithAction(Rot);
CCRotateBy *Rot1 = CCRotateBy::actionWithDuration(1.0f, 360);
CCRepeatForever *rep1 = CCRepeatForever::actionWithAction(Rot1);
tire->runAction(rep);
tire1->runAction(rep1);
```

but in box2d how to make? any example..

for collison detction for all thing planing to use  box2d.

Comment: you have to create the scene with auto scene = Scene::createWithPhysics() to enable physics in your scene;

Comment: @sunny1304  can u give some example to follow for box2d animations like above and for collsion detection

Answer (score 1):

cocos2D-x Doc contains an article about Box2D..
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/native/physics/physics-integration/en
not that detailed, but good enough to start with.

Also cocos2D-x framework test contains example of both Box2D and Chipmumk physics example.
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/native/getting-started/v3.0/how-to-run-cpp-tests-on-win32/en